# Significance of variation in otherwise linear data

Tags: statistical-significance, interpretation, linear

Say I have some data about preferred ice cream flavour from a sample of about 500 people.  I've taken their ages as well as their preferred flavour - vanilla (coded 0), licorice (coded 1) and chocolate (coded 2).  If age is broken into 12 categories of 5 years each (from 18-22, 23-27, etc), the tabulated frequency data looks like this:

```
      0  1  2
  0  29  0 12
  1  26  0  8
  2  24  1 29 <- significance?
  3  26  0 32 <- significance?
  4  30  0 14
  5  23  1 15
  6  32  1 23
  7  23  1 20
  8  20  0 29
  9  26  2 26
  10 11  0 12
  11  1  2  4
  12  1  0  1
```

Eyeballing the data, I can see a definite link between age and preference - the older you are, the more likely you are to prefer chocolate.  A chi square test including only chocolate and vanilla (as the licorice values are small) confirms this, with a p-value less than 0.02.

However, age group 2 and 3 goes against the overall trend.  People in these age groups are more likely to prefer chocolate, and in fact, age group 2 is more likely than *any* age group to choose chocolate.

Now, my question!: how would I go about finding the significance of the variation in the age groups 2 and 3 from the overall data?  I want to be determine whether this variation is statistically significant.

It's possible I am making some fundamental errors in my assumptions here, and I'm self-taught, so if I am misunderstanding something, please feel free to set me right.

Comment: As a prelude, make sure to take into account that the comparison is post hoc and should be tested in a different way than it would be if it were a priori.

Comment: Could you please explain a little further David?  From my perspective I basically have a spike in my data that looks important and is clear if you graph the data, but I'd like to back this up with a statistical justification. Surely there is some relatively straightforward way to do this?

Comment: The hardest part is defining the event. Do you want to find the probability that any 1, 2, or 3 consecutive outcomes are as extremely different from others as this or just two consecutive outcomes?. Is it right to consider only consecutive outcomes or would you have done the same analysis (whatever it is) if the spike had been for 2 and 4 instead of 2 and 3?  A  conservative approach is to count the number of possible outcomes you would have considered a spike and then multiple your p value by this number. You could collapse your data into two groups and do a 2 x 2 Chi Square test.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks David. Appreciate your taking the time to answer.